# Loop AJAX Response from php

Tags: php, ajax, response

I want to loop ajax response

```
response = [
             ["u.profile"],
             ["r.useractivity"],
             ["i.items_job"],
             ["i.setup"],
             ["search"],
             ["i.items_assortment"]
]
```

I want `data = u.profile;`
       `data = r.useractivity;`
       etc

Tried Method :

```
$.each(response,function(key,value){
    console.log(key+":"+value);
});
```

Getting error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [["u.profile"],["r.useractivity"],["i.items_job"],["i.setup"],["search"],["i.items_assortment"]]

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question I know its basic. But I am learning.

Comment: try transforming your JSON response to an object first `var response = JSON.parse(response)`, then you can iterate

Comment: you are looping array inside array not object , learn more about array of objects

Comment: Using JSON Parse method I was able to loop

var response = JSON.parse(response)

$.each(response,function(key,value){
  console.log(key+":"+value);
});

Thank you CodeGodie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `response` var is an array of arrays (an object) and the default keys are integers.
It would be an easier (and better) way if you could change it into an array of strings like this one :

```
var response = ["u.profile",
               "r.useractivity",
               "i.items_job",
               "i.setup",
               "search",
               "i.items_assortment"];
```

With this, you can easily loop your `response` like this :

```
for(var info in response)
    console.log(info+':'+response[info]);
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: Using JSON Parse method I was able to loop 

var response = JSON.parse(response) 

$.each(response,function(key,value){ 
console.log(key+":"+value); 
});

I tried your method and Its working too. Thank you tektiv